# Comparison of hydrogen bond strength

Tags: intermolecular-forces, hydrogen-bond

> Consider the following sets of H-bonds:
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> &\text{P:} &\ce{-O-H\bond{....}N} \\ 
> &\text{Q:} &\ce{-O-H\bond{....}O} \\
> &\text{R:} &\ce{-N-H\bond{....}N} \\
> &\text{S:} &\ce{-N-H\bond{....}O}
> \end{align}
> $$

Since oxygen is more electronegative $(\mathrm{EN})$ and polarises the hydrogen more than nitrogen, I think the order of decreasing strength is Q > P > S > R.

But the correct answer is P > Q > R > S. The reason given is that for H-bonding in

$$\ce{-A-H\bond{....}B}$$

to be strong, $\mathrm{EN}(\ce{A}) > \mathrm{EN}(\ce{B})$ and $\ce{B}$ should be electron-rich.

I am not able to understand where I went wrong.

Comment: A hint: Which one is a stronger base, $\ce{NH3}$ or $\ce{H2O}$?

Comment: @Poutnik NH3? I still don't get it,

Comment: Which ( Broensted-Lawry ) base is supposed to be more willing to bond to hydrogen by its free electron pair? A stronger one or a weaker one?

Comment: @Poutnik Thank you! I understand it now.

Comment: @Intermechanic If you got your answer, feel free to self-answer it.

Answer (score 2):

One way to understand this is through partial charges. A-H in −A−H⋅⋅⋅⋅B is acting as a hydrogen donor and B is acting as a hydrogen acceptor. H is partially positively charged in −A−H⋅⋅⋅⋅B. The more electron is withdrawn from the H, the more positively charged it is, and the more attraction there will be between H and B. Again, the H in −A−H⋅⋅⋅⋅B is partially positively charged, lacks electron density or is electron-poor, therefore it is attracted towards an electron-rich B.

Oxygen is more electronegative than nitrogen, it can make H to have a bigger partial positive charge than nitrogen can.  Nitrogen is less electronegative than oxygen, can put its partial negative charge into H⋅⋅⋅⋅B more readily than oxygen can.